# TestNG Parametric failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

Beginner testng always add the parameter error

Master please help look at

Thank you！！

java code：

```
public class NewTest{

@Parameters({"names"})
@Test
public void test(String name){
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

TestNGxml：

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
   <parameter name="names" values="aaaaaaaaaa"></parameter>
   <test name="Test">
       <classes>
            <class name="com.test.NewTest"/>
       </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Exception information：

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'names' is required by @Test on method Test 
but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in D:\Documents and Settings\huohui\workspace\lianxi\src\test.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should try `value="aaaaaaaaaa"`, not `values="aaaaaaaaaa"`?

Comment: Correct, the attribute is `"value"`, not `"values"`.